# Creating a Cassandra Connection Pool with JBoss

Tags: jboss, cassandra, connection, pool

I'm new to Cassandra and JBoss, and am trying to create a connection pool.  I've searched everywhere and found bits and pieces of information, but I'm still missing something.

I'm not clear on what I need in my standalone file, within the driver element.  What should I specify for driver-class and xa-datasource-class?

And, in module..xml, what path should I be using in the resource-root element?

I have these 2 jar files - are they correct?

cassandra-driver-core-2.0.2.jar

cassandra-driver-dse-2.0.2.jar

I'm able to open a connection and execute cql queries from a standalone Java class, but now I need to create a connection pool in JBoss.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra driver, itself maintains connection pool (atleast with datastax jars), which is configurable, in the run-time, 
and also can be configured while making the session.

On top of that cassandra driver even lets you read connection pool status, if you have chosen to do that. So you can create your own monitoring service for connection pool status.

So, not sure, what you are trying to achieve here, pool on top of another pool?

Comment: Thanks Abhishek.  No, I definitely don't want to create a pool on top of another pool.  I didn't know that the DataStax driver maintains its own connection pool.  I'll do some research and reading on this.  If you know of a site with a good explanation of this, I'd appreciate the link.  Thanks again, I'm learning this and appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Abhishek Anand , where can I get more details of creating connection pool , i am using java8 with datastax 3.7.2 version.